# Sort an Array in PHP by a specific value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, steam-web-api

How can i sort **[this](http://pastebin.com/dYwSGwgu)** array by `$data['response']['games'][x]['name']` alphabetical from A-Z?

I have tried already `array_multisort()` but didn't understand this function at all.

Hope you can help me - googled and searched this but didn't found any solution for my problem.

Edit: link updated.

**Code:** https://github.com/GabrielWanzek/GWSteamLib/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with [`usort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php), which allows you to define a custom comparison function:

```
usort($data['response']['games'], function($a, $b) {
    return strcmp($a['name'], $b['name']);
});
```

Note that `$data` is an object of type `stdClass`; it is not an array.

Comment: I have no idea why it was printed as object. This array is generated from `json_decode($content,true)` - i can handle it as an array.

This solution didn't worked for me

Comment: It is sorted - but not alphabetical. Warning: strcmp() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in C:\wamp\www\GIT\prj1\index.php on line 19

Comment: thanks but also the array isn't sorted. (it's sorted like in the file)

Answer (score 1):

Try following code:

```
$games = $data['response']['games']; // is array
usort($games, 'compareName');
var_dump($games);

# want to change $data?
# $data['response']['games'] = $games;

function compareName($a1, $a2) {
    return strcmp($a1['name'], $a2['name']);
}
```